# Why do i get more results from my mysql query in php then what i ask for?

Tags: php, mariadb

I am getting return values that do not exist in my current database. Even if i change my query the return array stays the same but missing values. How can this be what did i do wrong?
My MYSQL server version is 10.0.22 and this server gives me the correct result.
So the issue must be in PHP.

**My code:**

```
$select_query = "SELECT process_state.UID
FROM process_state 
WHERE process_state.UpdateTimestamp > \"[given time]\"";

$result = mysql_query($select_query, $link_identifier);

var_dump($result);
```

**Result:**

```
array(1) { 
[1]=> array(9) {
    ["UID"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["CreationTimestamp"]=> NULL 
    ["UpdateTimestamp"]=> NULL 
    ["ProcessState"]=> NULL  
    } 
}
```

**Solution:**
I have found this code somewhere in my program. The program used the same name ass mine. This function turns the MYSQL result into a array. This happens between the result view and my script. This was done to make the result readable.

```
parent::processUpdatedAfter($date);
```

**Function:**

```
public function processUpdatedAfter($date)
{
    $result = parent::processUpdatedAfter($date);
    $array = Array();

    if($result != false)
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $array[$row["UID"]]["UID"] = $row["UID"];
            $array[$row["UID"]]["CreationTimestamp"] = $row["CreationTimestamp"];
            $array[$row["UID"]]["UpdateTimestamp"] = $row["UpdateTimestamp"];
            $array[$row["UID"]]["ProcessState"] = $row["ProcessState"];
        }
        return $array;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I edited this and my script works fine now thanks for all the help.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: side note: use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: I doubt that this is all of your code. `mysql_query()` returns a resource and not an array.

Comment: @devpro The server where this is running does not have the support of PHP7. But the program needs to run on all the old systems with PHP5 or lower.

Comment: final test. if this is not the whole code, **1-** check that $result you are dump the same $result you assigned the result(no typos or something), **2-** and check if there any other assignment happened to $result between the query and dumping

Comment: Congratulations on getting it done. can you please give us a details on this function because googling it giving no result. is this a php core function?

Comment: @user56489870 no was self made function i will edit solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are `var_dump`ing a database resource handle and not the data you queried

You must use some sort of `fetch`ing process to actually retrieve that data generated by your query.

```
$ts = '2016-09-20 08:56:43';  
$select_query = "SELECT process_state.UID
                FROM process_state 
                WHERE process_state.UpdateTimestamp > '$ts'";

$result = mysql_query($select_query, $link_identifier);

// did the query work or is there an error in it
if ( !$result ) {
    // query failed, better look at the error message
    echo mysql_error($link_identifier);
    exit;
}

// test we have some results
echo 'Query Produced ' . mysql_num_rows($result) . '<br>';

// in a while loop if more than one row might be returned
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo $row['UID'] . '<br>';
}
```

> However I have to mention Every time you use [the `mysql_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Did not work did not get any result at all. The reason i use var_dump is to find out were things went wrong.  The funny thing is that CreationTimestamp does not exist it is called CreationTime. No clue where he get CreationTimestamp from that is a really old term i used a while back. But DB is dropt and recreated with new kolom names.

Comment: what is the value of `given time` @vincentpoortvliet

Comment: @vincentpoortvliet "No clue where he get CreationTimestamp from that is a really old term i used a while back"  .. are you sure you are querying the correct database ?

Comment: This part of your query looks odd for MYSQL `\"[given time]\"";` are you using MYSQL or SQLServer or something else

Comment: also run the query manually in PHP my admin: `SELECT process_state.UID
FROM process_state 
WHERE process_state.UpdateTimestamp > "yourDate"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: u want to check `$link_identifier` na :)

Comment: @user56489870 yes i am sure. i even changed the UID to test is i was using the right one. I am thinking in the lines of wrong memory allocation by PHP. But don't now how to check.

Comment: @user56489870 I know its tempting to blame the tools, but if we are honest 99.5% of the time, its us developers that have screwed up and not the tools

Comment: @devpro <pre> \"[given time]\""; </pre> is just to show you guys that a value needs to be put there. the query works fine but only in php things go wrong. getting correct result but not all the result and not with the correct keys connected to them.

Comment: and what happened when you used this example? can you please share the result? @vincentpoortvliet

Comment: @vincentpoortvliet . No. don't think that, php does not make mistakes. we do.  $result is not an array , it's is a resource , this is what you should get by var_dump it `resource(4) of type (mysql result)` how did you assign an array to it ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly all my other querys with the same link identifier work fine.

Comment: @user56489870 yes I was expecting that result as well but i got what I showed you guys. All the other mysql_ can't be used because of this reason.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have run the code you have given and I get <pre>Query Produced </pre> . No number is given because mysql_ functions aren't useble with this result.

Comment: than `echo $select_query;` and share. @vincentpoortvliet

Comment: @RiggsFolly SELECT UID FROM process_state 
WHERE UpdateTime > 2016-09-20 08:56:43

Comment: missing quotes? i tihnk: what happened, if you run this query in your PHP code `SELECT UID FROM process_state WHERE UpdateTime > '2016-09-20 08:56:43'`; @vincentpoortvliet

Comment: Then you did not copy the code accurately. There shoudl have been single quotes around that date and time, but that shoudl have activated the Error Message code.

Comment: @devpro not the issue

Comment: @vincentpoortvliet: not the issue what? working or not? getting result?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have to edit the query because i can't show all the kolom names. But there is nothing wrong with the query. But more with the way i am am getting my return value.

Comment: Oh **HANG ON** I may have been right a while back. ___You said My MYSQL server version is 10.0.22___ There is no MYSQL Server version with that number ___But there is a SQLServer with that version___

Comment: @RiggsFolly he is using Maria DB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-10022-release-notes/

Comment: or if anyone want to learn "HOW TO DEBUG?" than follow this.. :)

Comment: Yes i am use sing MariaDB 10.0.22.

Comment: Can I make sure of something. Are you using EXACTLY the code I have posted in my answer?

Comment: Oh I just amended it to use the date you were using in your query

Comment: @vincentpoortvliet if you can shutdown the webserver(and php) and the mysql server and restart them again with fresh memory. why don't you give it a shot ? I think PHP does query cache , and mysql does the same. and see what will happen with the first query result

Comment: is there any badge for long long conversations? :)

Comment: @devpro Well we both deserve it if there is :) I already deleted some of my sillier ones to keep the list a little shorter

Comment: my vote for you for better explanation and debugging.

Comment: Thanks: I was going to UV your answer, now that has made me get round to it

Comment: @devpro I would love to know who UV's Navnit's answer. Obviously he has friends in low places

Answer (score 3):

Note that, `var_dump($result);` will only return the resource not data.

You need to `mysql_fetch_*` for getting records.

**Example with MYSQLi Object Oriented:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT process_state.UID
FROM process_state 
WHERE process_state.UpdateTimestamp > \"[given time]\"";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['UID'];
    }    
} 
else 
{
    echo "No record found";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**Side Note:** i suggest you to use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) because `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in PHP 7.

Comment: I am guessing by the sudden silence, the OP has spotted what was wrong and has disappeared in a puff of smoke. I have definitely run out of steam on this question. I cannot see what is wrong, unless we are not being told the whole story, which I suspect is the case

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I did not ran off but was still testing stuff my self. The reason of no respons is there was nothing to respond to anymore ;)

Comment: Well there was a request from me to check you were using exactly the code I posted, so we all knew what we were trying to debug. And a check that you had seen an amendment to my posted code.

Comment: @devpro **Swear-word, swear-word** and another **swear-word**. See the question!!! OP has posted the solution!!!! OP as suspected was showing us code that seems to be totally nothing like the code he was actually using. **Thats an hour+ of my/our life(s) we will never get to see again**

Comment: @RiggsFolly: no words.. :)

Comment: @devpro I have a head full, but I cannot write any of them here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$select_query = "SELECT `UID` FROM `process_state ` WHERE `UpdateTimestamp` > \"[given time]\" ORDER BY UID DESC ";

$result = mysql_query($select_query, $link_identifier);

var_dump($result);
```

Try this hope it will works

Comment: And exactly WHAT difference is this going to make?

Comment: Did not work :) but i don't think ordering my result will fix anything but thanks for the respons.

Comment: is there any problem ??